# git - proper work flow for starting new feature branch

Tags: git, branch

i need to create a new feature for a project on github.  i have access to the account.  I created a new branch off the master called 'myBranch'.  Than, in terminal I ran `git clone https://github.com/test/example.git`.  Now if I run git branch -a I see that I am checked out on master and my newly created branch is in red.

Was it a mistake to create the new branch on github?  Because now it is a remote branch and what I really want is to start working on the new feature locally.

My question is two fold.  Should I have created the branch locally by cloning the remote repo then running `git branch 'someNewBranch'`.  In that case I would simply checkout that branch and start working on the project and commit as normal and than push?  Would that create a new remote branch on github that is a duplicate of my new local branch?  And alternatively, given that I already created a remote branch through github's interface, is there a common way to simply begin working on that branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is an mistake to have it as an remote branch. It is proper practice that you keep the history of what you did on github.

For your question. If you first cloned and created a branch, it wouldn't have a remote equivalent yet. But the moment you try to push, you have to create a remote branch anyway. Git will never create a remote branch automatically (with the default settings). It will give the following message:

```
fatal: The current branch blob has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin <yourbranchname>
```

If you do this with the remote branch already created, you can connect the branches by setting upstream as above. Or you pull and do a checkout:

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

The easiest way to just start a branch and work on it is:

```
git branch <yourbranchname>
git checkout <yourbranchname>
```

And then when you made some commits:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <yourbranchname>
```

But there is nothing wrong with having a remote branch for features. That way other developers can check it out too.

If you are done working on your branch you can merge it with master (or your development branch):

```
    git checkout develop
    git merge <branchname>
```

and then tag it with the name of the feature:

```
    git tag feature/<myfeaturename>
```

You can even sign it to state you are the owner, if you have a gpg key laying around:

```
   git tag -s feature/myfeature
```

Then you can delete it safely again:

```
   git branch -d <mybranch>
```

Then you know, when you merged you feature into your development branch and keep your list of branches from growing

Comment: thank you for the answer.  Are you saying that after i've cloned the remote repo/directory i  can create a new branch on my local computer.  make some changes, add a feature and commit -m "newFeature".  Then, when I go to push i need to set an upstream?  I don't understand this.  Isn't the upstream already set to the github I cloned from?

Comment: I meant, that when you have created a remote branch (say through the github branch menu), you may create a local branch with the same name without pulling and then do some work there and push it with setting origin. That will work just fine. 

Of course by pulling you already get them. I will edit the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. Actually you can push your code to other copies of your repositories with push too.  Hence the need of origin. Origin is just an alias for the repo you cloned from.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the branch on github, that is, as you said it, a remote branch. Now you just need to fetch it locally:

```
git fetch origin
```

At this point you'll have a local copy of your feature branch.

Start working on it by doing:

```
git checkout your-feature-branch
```

If instead you created the branch locally first, you do this to create it on github and push:

```
git push --set-upstream-to origin your-feature-branch
```